# how to tail the w command

Tags: linux, bash

is there a way to track who has logged in or out in real time. At the moment I run w but it exits as soon as it is done. I am thinking there might be some way to tail the w command or run it continuously.

Comment: try the `watch` command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following command :

```
watch -n1 w
```

Comment: fantastic just what I needed

Comment: This is great, and useful!

Answer (score 1):

login/logout info is stored at `/var/log/wtmp*` also (http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl5_wtmp.htm)

you can get those info by `watch last`

Comment: this is also helpful but the other answer is closer to what I needed on the fly

Answer (score 0):

You could run it in a infinite while loop, and throw off prompts whenever a new user enters.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
b=`w|cut -d' ' -f1`;
while (true)
    do
        a=`w|cut -d' ' -f1`;
        if [ "$b" != "$a" ]
            then
            echo "new user!";
        fi
        b=$a;
    sleep 1;
    done
```